# Host is not allowed to connect every time I try to create a DataSet in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, dataset

I'm trying to create some `DataSets` using the wizard in `Visual Studio 2013`. The first time I create the connection to the `MySQL` server it works fine, than if I try to use that connection again I get :

> Host 'MyPc' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL Server

No problem if I create a new connection every time I create a new `DataSet`.

UPDATE:

This seems to be a probem with the MySQL connector, after some time the connection in my Server Explorer in Visual Studio just goes off with a red x. If I update them and then create a Dataset everything works fine. Is MySQL killing my connection after sometime ?